# Pre-create inner Mono as a variable

Tags: java, project-reactor

Assume simple reactive stream line this:

```
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .flatMap(i -> 
                        Mono.just(i)
                                .map( ... map some value)
                                .flatMap( ... async call)
                                .map(... more mappings)
                )
                .doOnNext(log::info)
                .blockLast()
        ;
```

Assume Mono inside parent stream `.flatMap()` is complicated reactive stream with complex logic. Is there a way to save that Mono as a variable that could be passed to the parent stream? In other words, something like this:

```
final Function<Integer, Publisher<String>> monoPublisher = Mono.something()
                .map( ... map some value)
                .flatMap( ... async call)
                .map(... more mappings);

        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .flatMap(monoPublisher)
                .doOnNext(log::info)
                .blockLast()
        ;
```

The naive answer would be:

```
final Function<Integer, Publisher<String>> monoPublisher = i -> Mono.just(i) ...
```

However, that would still defer initialization of Mono until actual subscription, and new Mono would be created for each element in parent stream.

I am familiar with `Mono.create()` but I don't see how to make it work here, without creating my own `Publisher` implementation that wraps around sink that is returned by `Mono.create()`

EDIT:
Thanks for ESala for the suggestion. I just modified his example to use ThreadLocal instead of Queue, which is not needed for this example using Flux.just() but would prevent race conditions when using multi-threaded producer

```java
final ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocalStorage = new ThreadLocal<>();

        final Mono<String> mono = Mono.fromSupplier(threadLocalStorage::get)
                .map(Objects::toString);

        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .flatMap(i -> {
                    threadLocalStorage.set(i);
                    return mono;
                })
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .blockLast()
        ;
```

Comment: Look at the `Tuples.of` in the reactor code library.

Comment: Can you provide more context on why is the _naive answer_ not suitable? In general it should not matter that a new `Mono` is created for each element in the outer `Flux`.

Comment: that sounds overly complicated. and if there is a `map`, then surely you DO need the input value, so your second snippet... just works.

Comment: @ESala - in general it doesn't matter, but but what if you inner Mono has 100 operators and is build programmatically. Its very inefficient to build it for each element in outer Flux.  Its much more efficient to have Mono that is already built so the only object that is created is a a new subscription.  When you have each server handling > 15K requests/sec we need to use any performance optimization and garbage collection is an issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work, just replace the `LinkedList` with something fancier that supports concurrent access:

```java
Queue<Integer> arguments = new LinkedList<>();

Publisher<String> expensivePublisher =
        Mono.fromSupplier(arguments::remove)
                .map( ... map some value)
                .flatMap( ... async call)
                .map(... more mappings);

Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .flatMap(
                i -> {
                    arguments.add(i);
                    return expensivePublisher;
                })
        .blockLast();
```

But it still feels like a hack. If there truly are 100 operators in the inner, then would suggest trying to optimize on that side. Improvements in that area will likely have higher impact than reusing the `Publisher` to avoid recreating it.

Comment: thanks for this. Didn't know Mono.fromSupplier calls supplier to get value on each subscription, I thought it calls it once on assembly. This will work. I agree its still a bit of a hack but its a lot less code than the wrapper that I wrote.